# Always round up to a specific decimal place?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rounding

I have 42.4300001 and I want the value to be 42.44. Is there a nifty way to get this done in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6e74e94c403eb914b25b6949a0e1ed68)

```
SELECT ceil(42.4300001 * 100) / 100
```

`ceil()` always rounds to next integer. Result: `42.4400000000000000`

To cut the trailing zero you could do a

`trunc(result, 2)` or cast to `result::decimal(digits, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

One way is

```
trunc(42.4300001::numeric + 0.00999999999999999999999999, 2)
```

The cast to `numeric` is necessary for the two-argument `trunc` function.

**Note:** This will only work reliably for `real` and `double precision` numbers.

Comment: This adds 1 to the left side of the decimal place and doesn't round the `.43` to `.44`

Comment: Oh, sorry, fixed.

Comment: Your fix will not work with `42.44` which is still rounded. But your solution will add nevertheless.

Comment: That's easily remedied.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't believe that adding a number is a general solution add all. This would be wrong again: `42.4300000000000000000000000000001`

Comment: I have been assuming that this question is about `real` or `double precision` data. In that case, my solution is reliable, because they have limited precision. Your criticism is well-founded when it comes to `numeric` numbers like the one you quote. I have added a note about that.